# Using split function in PySpark

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to search a particular line from a very big log file. I am able to search the line.

Now using that line space I want to create a dataframe,I  am unable to do that. I have tried below code but unable to achieve.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext
from pyspark import  SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import *

conf=SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("invparsing")
sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)
sql=SQLContext(sc)
def f(x) :print(x)

data_frame_schema=StructType([
    StructField("Typeof",StringType()),
    #StructField("Produt_mod",StringType()),
    #StructField("Col2",StringType()),
    #StructField("Col3",StringType()),
    #StructField("Col4",StringType()),
    #StructField("Col5",StringType()),
])
path="C:/rk/IBMS/inv.log"

lines=sc.textFile(path)
NodeStr=lines.filter(lambda x:'Node :RBS6301' in x).map(lambda x:x.split(" +"))
NodeStr.foreach(f)
Nodedf=sql.createDataFrame(NodeStr,data_frame_schema)
Nodedf.show(truncate=False)
```

Now, I am getting output here - only one single string. O want to split value on the basis of space.

```
[u'Node: RBS6301         XP10521/26 R30F L17A.4-6 (C17.0_LSV_PS4)']
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|Typesof                                                      |  
+-------------------------------------------------------------+ 
|Node: RBS6301         XP10521/26   R30F   L17A.4-6   (C17.0_LSV_PS4)
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Expected output:

```
Typeof      Produt_mod  Col2          Col3    Col4        COL5 
Node     RBS6301       XP10521/26    R30F    L17A.4-6    C17.0_LSV_PS4
```

Answer (score 2):

The first mistake you made is here:

```
lambda x:x.split(" +")
```

`str.split` takes a constant string not a regular expression. To split on a whitespace you should just omit separator

```
lines = sc.parallelize(["Node: RBS6301         XP10521/26 R30F L17A.4-6 (C17.0_LSV_PS4)"])

lines.map(lambda s: s.split()).first()
# ['Node:', 'RBS6301', 'XP10521/26', 'R30F', 'L17A.4-6', '(C17.0_LSV_PS4)']
```

Once you've done that you can just filter and convert to a `DataFrame`:

```
df = lines.map(lambda s: s.split()).filter(lambda x: len(x) == 6).toDF(
    ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6"]
)
df.show()
# +-----+-------+----------+----+--------+---------------+
# | col1|   col2|      col3|col4|    col5|           col6|
# +-----+-------+----------+----+--------+---------------+
# |Node:|RBS6301|XP10521/26|R30F|L17A.4-6|(C17.0_LSV_PS4)|
# +-----+-------+----------+----+--------+---------------+
```

and `filter`:

```
df[df["col2"] == "RBS6301"].show()
# +-----+-------+----------+----+--------+---------------+
# | col1|   col2|      col3|col4|    col5|           col6|
# +-----+-------+----------+----+--------+---------------+
# |Node:|RBS6301|XP10521/26|R30F|L17A.4-6|(C17.0_LSV_PS4)|
# +-----+-------+----------+----+--------+---------------+
```

Comment: This is just for sake of reproducible. If your file contained only that one line, the result of `textFile` would be the same.

Comment: @user9613381
I am getting my expected line from log file by using 
:'NodeStr=lines.filter(lambda x:'Node :RBS6301' in x).map(lambda x:x.split(" +"))'

tell me after that how can i use your code or there is a different way to search a particular string in pyspark and create data frame from that ....

Comment: Please read my answer again. `lambda x:x.split(" +")` is exactly the wrong part :)

Comment: now using this i am getting my expected line : 
NodeStr = lines.filter(lambda x: 'Node: RBS6301' in x)...
 now tell me sir how i will go further...
if i am placing next line this 
Test_lines = sc.parallelize(NodeStr)
 it is not working ..

My question was i have a log file from that i want to select a particular line and with that line i want to create Data Frame...

Comment: The code I posted above (`df = lines.map(lambda s: s.split()).filter(lambda x: len(x) == 6).toDF(
    ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6"]
)` followed by `df[df["col2"] == "RBS6301"]` (or  `df.filter("col2 = 'RBS6301'")`) is the exact code you need, as long as data matches the one included in the question.

Comment: it is working fine only file contain that row only...log file is very huge and multi line with variable in length.1st df returning some value after filtering it is not retiring any value ,returning a blank data frame. same thing i am able to implement using Scala,but not able to do it in pyspark. so there is now way i can directly filter out the row which i need and crate data-frame using only that line .

Comment: Without seeing actual data I cannot help you more.

Comment: dfjhgjsf  
sdgfsjgsfgdf;g;d  
sdfsifskf  
sfksgfskg  
Node: RBS6301                   CXP102051/26_R30F L17A.4-6 (C17.0_LSV198_PA24)
=================================
col1  clo2  clo3
=================================
1 avb  wer21g2
---------------------------------

=================================
col12 col13 col14
=================================
12d sf sdf22
asf2 asdfw2 df21df
dsf21 sdf2 df2
-------------------------------------
fgdgd
dgfdhd
segdfhfhjfjghj

Comment: dfjhgjsf <\n>
sdgfsjgsfgdf;g;d <\>
sdfsifskf<\n>
sfksgfskg<\n>
Node: RBS6301                   CXP102051/26_R30F L17A.4-6 (C17.0_LSV198_PA24)<\n>
=================================<\n>
col1  clo2  clo3<\n>
=================================<\n>
1 avb  wer21g2<\n>
---------------------------------<\n>

=================================<\n>
col12 col13 col14<\n>
=================================<\n>
12d sf sdf22<\n>
asf2 asdfw2 df21df<\n>
dsf21 sdf2 df2 <\n>
-------------------------------------<\n>
fgdgd<\n>
dgfdhd<\n>
segdfhfhjfjghj<\n>

Comment: please considered 2nd comments..this is sample data set .added "<\n> " for line breaking